# Incorrect data from Yahoo Finance with yfinance with incorrect dates

Tags: google-play, finance, stock, yahoo, yfinance

When trying to get stock market data from yahoo finance with yfinance, I often get data with incorrect dates:

```
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
```

with

```
start = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
data = yf.download('AAPL', start=start, end=end, progress=False)
print(data.tail())
```

The output is:

```
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
Date                                                                     
2021-08-31  152.660004  152.800003  151.289993  151.830002  151.830002   
2021-09-01  152.830002  154.979996  152.339996  152.509995  152.509995   
2021-09-02  153.869995  154.720001  152.399994  153.649994  153.649994   
2021-09-03  153.759995  154.630005  153.089996  154.300003  154.300003   
2021-09-22  144.449997  145.880005  143.700104  145.250000  145.250000   

                Volume  
Date                    
2021-08-31  8632380000  
2021-09-01  8031370000  
2021-09-02  7117130000  
2021-09-03  5780870000  
2021-09-22    32404592
```

Why does this date discrepancy error happen? (**09-03** -> **09-22**)

Comment: At what time did you fetch this data? It's past market close (which is a possible cause), and my data looks fine. With `yfinance` and the yahoo data as a source, you might get the occasional missing day. Multiple weeks missing for A-list tickers, that should be uncommon, though. Good financial data, especially when it's free, is rare. See also [Why is Michael Bloomberg so rich](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2019/11/heres-why-mike-bloomberg-is-so-rich.html)

Comment: This is an issue for me too. I also have gotten back different data in some cases.
Currently the dataset always ends on 2021-09-03, it used to give me 2021-09-03 and then the current day.

Thinking I should use a different stock history service.